# Acquia Dev Desktop create-project Fails With 404 Error at Repository

Tags: composer, acquia-dev-desktop

I am using a brand new installation of Acquia Dev Desktop on Windows 10.  When I try to use composer to create a new project I get the following output using the `-vvv` option:

```
composer create-project drupal/drupal-project:8.x    hhc  --no-interaction  --no-install  -vvv
```

> Downloading https://packagist.phpcomposer.com/packages.json
> [200] https://packagist.phpcomposer.com/packages.json
> Writing C:/Users/JimD/AppData/Local/Composer/repo/https---packagist.phpcomposer.com/packages.json into cache
> Downloading https://packagist.phpcomposer.com/p2/drupal/recommended-project.json
> [404] https://packagist.phpcomposer.com/p2/drupal/recommended-project.json
>
> [InvalidArgumentException]
> Could not find package drupal/recommended-project with version 8.x.

This happens with both composer versions `1.10` and `2.0.7`.
I have tried all of the following and got the same result after each.

- composer clear-cache
- upgrade from version `1.10.13` to `2.0.7`
- clear-cache and composer reloaded all the `.json` files from repository in to cache.
- Uninstalled Acquia and removed all file folders related to composer.
- Tried different `--stability` options
- Tried installing project for other platform

  composer create-project -n concrete5/composer dreamrs  --no-install  -vvv

Tried repositories https://repo.packagist.org and https://packagist.phpcomposer.com

In every case I get the "Could not find package" error.

**EDITED:**
Latest effort, I downloaded the recommended-project.json file, put it in an empty folder and ran `composer install -vvv`.  I got a 404 error for every package.  Here are some examples:

[404] https://packages.drupal.org/files/packages/8/p2/drupal/core-dev.json

[404] https://packages.drupal.org/files/packages/8/p2/drupal/core-composer-scaffold.json

Any idea what is going on here?  I can download other packges such as hirak/prestissimo and grasmash/composerize-drupal.

Comment: It's `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project my_site_name_dir`. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies

Comment: Can you install anything at all? Maybe network problems? Firewall? Can you try a different computer?

Comment: Does not look that way.  Just tried this:C:\Acquia\Sites\test>composer --version
Composer version 2.0.7 2020-11-13 17:31:06

C:\Acquia\Sites\test>composer require 'drupal/admin_toolbar:2.4'


  [UnexpectedValueException]
  Could not parse version constraint 2.4': Invalid version string "2.4'"

Comment: I can load https://packages.drupal.org/8/packages.json in a browser. Yet ALL of the .json urls sent  return a 404.
[404] https://packages.drupal.org/files/packages/8/p2/drupal/core-composer-scaffold.json.  The URLs being sent are wrong. No idea why.

Comment: I changed to composer v 1.10.17 and it started working.  No other changes.  Today I upgraded to 2.0.7.  Everything is fine.  I changed nothing else on my machine.  It works now, and composer 2.0.7 is lightening fast compared to 1.10.17